# sqlplus limit exceeded

Tags: sql, oracle, unix, plsql, oracle11g

I have a table t2 which contains table names and their column names.I have written plsql block in sql file to generate the scripts dynamically for each table using shell.One of the table (AAA) has 250 columns due to which i am getting error Input is too long. this error comes while printing the header.

sample data

```
create table t2 (table_nm varchar2(10), col_nm varchar2(10));
DECLARE 
 i number := 0;
BEGIN
  loop  
   insert into t2 values ('AAA','COLUMN_'||i);
    i:= i+1;
   EXIT WHEN I=250;
   commit;
  END LOOP;
end;
/
```

sql.file.

```
SET termout OFF
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON 
SET echo OFF
SET feedback OFF
SET timing OFF
spool v_out.sql
DECLARE
  CURSOR c1
  IS
    SELECT rnm,
      cnt,
      tbl_col_nm,
      col_nm,
      table_nm,
      LVL_NBR
    FROM
      (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  EXTR.TABLE_NM ORDER BY EXTR.COL_NM)   AS RNM,
        COUNT(EXTr.COL_NM) OVER (PARTITION BY  EXTR.TABLE_NM ORDER BY EXTR.TABLE_NM) AS CNT,
        EXTR.TABLE_NM
        ||'.'
        ||extr.COL_NM AS TBL_COL_NM,
        extr.col_nm col_nm,
        extr.table_nm,
        1 as lvl_nbr
      FROM T2 EXTR
      WHERE  TABLE_NM = 'AAA'
      )
  ORDER BY lvl_nbr DESC,
    table_nm,
    rnm;
  v_col_list      VARCHAR2(4000)  := '';
  v_header_select VARCHAR2(4000)  := '';
  v_sql           VARCHAR2(32767) := '';
  v_from_clause   VARCHAR2(4000)  := '';
  v_table_nm      VARCHAR2(100)   := '';
  v_rec_count     NUMBER          := 0;
  err_code        VARCHAR2(100);
  err_msg         VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
  FOR i IN c1
  LOOP
    IF i.rnm = 1 THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('set colsep ,');
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('set pagesize 0');
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('set trimspool on');
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('set headsep off');
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('set feedback off');
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('set echo off');
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('set timing off');
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('set termout off');
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('set linesize 32767');
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SET VERIFY OFF');
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SET HEADING OFF');
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SET NEWPAGE NONE');
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('COLUMN SCRIPT FORM A3000');
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('spool '||i.table_nm||'_'||TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYYMMDD')||'.dat ');
      V_COL_LIST      := '';
      v_header_select := chr(13);
      v_sql           := '';
      v_table_nm      := i.table_nm;
      v_from_clause   := v_table_nm;
    END IF;
    v_col_list := v_col_list || i.col_nm || '|';
    IF i.rnm    = i.cnt THEN
      v_col_list := rtrim(v_col_list, '|' );
      v_sql    := v_sql || i.tbl_col_nm || '  ' ;
    ELSE
       v_sql := v_sql || i.tbl_col_nm || CHR(10) || '|| ''|'' || ' ;
    END IF;
    IF I.RNM           = I.CNT THEN
      V_HEADER_SELECT := 'SELECT '|| V_HEADER_SELECT || '''' || V_COL_LIST || '''' ||' FROM DUAL ;';
      V_SQL           := ' SELECT ' || V_SQL ||' AS ot ' || CHR(10) || ' FROM ' ||V_FROM_CLAUSE || CHR(10)||' ;';
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_header_select);
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('spool off');
END;
/
spool OFF
@v_out.sql;
SET serveroutput OFF
```

Any suggestions on how to get rid of this error . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When I tried this code from Oracle SQL*Plus i got the following error -

```
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "'COLUMN_0|..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "_104|COLUM..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "|COLUMN_11..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "LUMN_118|C..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0044: For a list of known commands enter HELP
and to leave enter EXIT.
```

I updated the code to remove the assignment -

```
v_header_select := chr(13);
```

After running code with this change, there was no error and the column heading got printed in the spool file AAA_20180530.dat.

Hope this resolves your issue as well.

Comment: i am still getting the same error even after removing the assignment. my spool file AAA_20180530.dat. prints SP2-0027: Input is too long (> 2499 characters) - line ignored

Comment: How about adding a line feed as follows -  V_HEADER_SELECT := 'SELECT '|| V_HEADER_SELECT || '''' || V_COL_LIST || '''' ||chr(10)||' FROM DUAL ;';

Comment: @Shrek.This is also not working.

Comment: @Shrek.This is also not working. So i just split the line by using  v_header_select := substr(v_header_select,1,1520)|| chr(10)||substr(v_header_select,1521) || chr(10); and it worked fine for me but another issue is the blank line after the heading. I have checked all the setting but no luck.. Any idea how can i remove the extra space.